# Is the convolution of two $L^1$ bounded function Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convolution, lipschitz-functions

while solving a completely different problem, I have come to this result:

> Let $f,g: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be two functions bounded by $C_f,C_g$ respectively. If at least one, say $f$ is in $L^1$, the convolution $f*g$ is $2C_f\cdot C_g-$Lipschitz continuous

My proof:

Let $\varepsilon>0$, and $x\in \mathbb R$. Let $a,b$ be an interval such that
$$\int_{\mathbb R-[a,b]} |f(y)|\ dy\le \varepsilon$$
($a,b$ exists since $f\in L^1$) then, we have $|f*g(x+z)-f*g(x)|=$
$$\bigg |\int_{\mathbb R} f(y)g(x+z-y)dy- \int_{\mathbb R}f(y)g(x-y)dy\bigg |\le 2C_g\varepsilon + \bigg |\int_a^b f(y)g(x+z-y)dy- \int_a^b f(y)g(x-y)dy\bigg | $$
which can be rewritten as
$$2C_g\varepsilon + \bigg |\int_b^{b+z} f(y)g(x-y)dy- \int_a^{a+z} f(y)g(x-y)dy\bigg |\le 2C_g\varepsilon + 2C_fC_f|z|$$

this being valid for every $\varepsilon>0$, we get that the whole function is $2C_fC_g$ Lipschitz.

If this result is correct, **Where can I find a reference for this?**

and, more important **Is this true also in higher dimension?**

EDIT:

Unfortunately, the result is not true, a possible counterexample is given by the couple

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{100} 1_{[i,i+1/100]}(x),\ g(x)=1_{[0,1/100]}(x).$$

As pointed by
PhoemueX in the comment, the rewriting at step 4 is incorrect.

Comment: How do you get the step after "this can be rewritten as"? Can you add more details? Somehow I find your claimed fact very surprising (meaning that I doubt it is actually true).

Comment: You are right, I've found a counterexample.